# Loading multiple .mat files into a matrix and performing operations on it

Tags: matlab, matrix, file-read, directory-listing, mat-file

I have 429 numerical matrices of identical size (107 rows by 36 columns), stored inside sequentially named `.mat` files (e.g: `subj_00000.mat ... subj_00428.mat`). Here's what I need to do:

1. Import into the MATLAB workspace.
2. After importing, average all of them to generate another matrix, which will also have a dimension of 107x36.
3. Finally, linearly correlate each column of the average matrix with each column of each of the original 429 matrices, to generate a new matrix of 429 rows and 36 columns.

So far I got to the stage of building a 107 x 36 x 429 array to be filled with my set of matrices.

```
S = dir(fullfile(D,'subj*.mat')); % D is the path where the .mat files are saved
N = numel(S);
C = cell(1,N); % preallocate cell array
for k = 1:N
    S = load(fullfile(D,S(k).name));
    C(k) = struct2cell(S);
end
A = cat(3,C{:}); % join all of the original matrices into a 107x36x429 array
M = mean(A,3)
```

but I get the following error message:

```
Reference to non-existent field 'name'.
Error in myscript (line 6)
S = load(fullfile(D,S(k).name));
```

Comment: So which part of the process are you having a problem with? If you say "all of them", I'm afraid your question will be closed as "too broad" and downvoted as "[no attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)". Please show us what you've done so far, and which **specific** step you're struggling with (or would like advice on optimizing, if that's the case).

Answer (score 0):

> You are looping over S yet overwriting it every time. Rename the S that is inside the loop. While you are at it I would give all your variables meaningful names--there is no need to use a single letter every time. – svdc

Thank you! I renamed

```
S = load(fullfile(D,S(k).name));
```

as

```
T = load(fullfile(D,S(k).name));
```

and it worked